# Extracting a variable from a netCDF file using python without value repeating

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf

I try to output the precipitation for each year but when `print precip` executes I get the same value which is `9.969209968386869e+36`.

```
import arcpy
import numpy
import netCDF4
f =netCDF4.Dataset('Y:\\Projects\\ToriW\\NC Files\\TP40Years.nc', 'r',Format='NetCDF4')

#The dimensions and variables of the netCDF file
lon = numpy.array(f.variables['lon'][:])
lat = numpy.array(f.variables['lat'][:])
time =numpy.array(f.variables['time'][:])
precip = numpy.array(f.variables['pre'][:], dtype=type(f.variables))  
for i in time:
      print ("Precipitation for:", i)
      print (precip[i][:][:])
```

My question is how do I remove this number?  I have tried the numpy.putmask, but the big number keeps being outputted.  What else can I do?

Comment: so what is your question? The 9.969209968386869e+36 is likely a fill value denoting missing data.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `[:][:]` in that the `precip` print?